# Appointment in RadScheduler not show on search

Tags: c#, css, telerik, radscheduler

I have a radscheduler and search button that populate Schduler, when I search and reload radschduler with RadAjaxManager, appointments do not appear open, when I click, if shown. why?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YEq2.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Solved, I need to add properties for weekview

[WeekView DayStartTime="00:00:00"                        DayEndTime="23.00:00"                          GroupingDirection="Horizontal"                        ShowResourceHeaders="true"                        UserSelectable="false" ]